# If $G$ is an uncountable group and $H$ is a subgroup then $G$ \ $H$ is uncountable ?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $G$ be an uncountable group and $H$ be an uncountable proper subgroup , then is $G$ \ $H$ uncountable ? I tried using that $G=H \cup(\cup_{x\in G-H}xH)$ , but didn't get anywhere . Please help

Comment: Is it the set difference? Then you should mention that $gH$ is of the same cardinality as $H$ for $g\in G$.

Comment: @FrankScience: Yes $G-H$ is indeed the set difference and $xH$ do have same cardinality as that of $H$

Comment: But different $gH$'s are disjoint, therefore $G\setminus H$ is uncountable.

Comment: @FrankScience: But how ?? a countable union of uncountable sets is also  uncountable ...

Comment: @SouvikDey Let $x \in G \setminus H$. Then $xH \subseteq G \setminus H$ and $xH$ is uncountable.

Comment: @SouvikDey: If $H$ is a _proper_ subgroup, then there is a $g\notin H$, and then $gH$ is a coset that is disjoint from $H$ and therefore is a subset of $G\setminus H$. Since $G\setminus H$ has an uncountable subset, it is uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

To see that $G \setminus H$ is uncountable it suffices to note that $G$ is the disjoint union of co-sets modulo $H$, among them $H$ itself. Each co-set has the same cardinality as $H$ and there are at least two as the subgroup is proper. Thus at least one is contained in $G \setminus H$, which is the union of all co-sets but $H$, and the cardinality of $G \setminus H$ is at least that of $H$.

On the other hand, following up on a comment, it is not true that the number of cosets, so the cardinality of $G/H$ is necessarily uncountable or even infinite. To see this if $H$ is some uncountable group, and $G'$ whatever group than setting $G = H \times G'$ we get $G/H$ is isomorphic to $G'$, and $G'$ was arbitrary.